# How to create one procedure to grant privileges

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm the DBA administrator, and i want to create the following procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRUEBAS.TOMAPRIVILEGIOS(USUARIOS VARCHAR) AS
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE CONNECT TO '||USUARIOS||'';   
    END TOMAPRIVILEGIOS;
/
```

But appear one error.

```
BEGIN PRUEBAS.TOMAPRIVILEGIOS('PRUEBAS'); END;
Informe de error -
ORA-00990: falta el privilegio o no es válido
ORA-06512: en "PRUEBAS.TOMAPRIVILEGIOS", línea 3
ORA-06512: en línea 1
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do DDL in a procedure, you need to use dynamic SQL.  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is probably the easiest way to do so.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE( p_username IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
  l_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'GRANT CONNECT TO ' || dbms_assert.schema_name( p_username );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END;
```

Generally, it's easiest to build up the string you want to execute in a local variable and then pass that to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  That makes debugging much easier when you can just log the string you've built rather than trying to figure out what the syntax error is.  When you're using dynamic SQL, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks so you want to verify your inputs with either the `dbms_assert` package or through some custom means.

As an aside, you probably want to create custom roles rather than relying on something like `CONNECT`.  Oracle removed a bunch of permissions from `CONNECT` in 10.2 so that it now only allows database connections but in prior versions it was much more powerful than the name implies.  You generally ought not use the `CONNECT` and `RESOURCE` roles, you're generally better off creating your own roles with the exact privileges you want.

Comment: Thanks Justin, now Works fine!!